# Lost link with Sprite texture

Tags: c++, sfml

I have this class to add Sprites to my game:

```
class Pickup {
   public:
       Pickup::Pickup()
       {
            Texture healthTexture;
            healthTexture.loadFromFile("health.png");
            m_Sprite.setTexture(healthTexture);
        } 
       Sprite Pickup::getSprite()
       {
            return m_Sprite;
       }
   private: 
        Sprite m_Sprite;
};
```

I use Pickup nameSprite() to add another sprite to my game. But every time I do this (I tried with different images, I used `if(!healthTexture.loadFromFile(..))`to see if the problem is with the image) I only see a white rectangle instead of what I wanted, and nothing seems to be wrong. My question is: what is the cause for the link problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SFML documentation](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Sprite.php#a3729c88d88ac38c19317c18e87242560) states:

> The texture argument refers to a texture that must exist as long as
>   the sprite uses it. Indeed, the sprite doesn't store its own copy of
>   the texture, but rather keeps a pointer to the one that you passed to
>   this function. If the source texture is destroyed and the sprite tries
>   to use it, the behaviour is undefined.

The Texture Object you create and load is local to your constructor and destroyed at its end, so once it is actually used later in your programs execution, the pointer/reference kept by the Sprite-Object is dangling.

To avoid the issue you could, for instance, save the Texture as an additional member in your Pickup class.

As pointed out by Lorence Hernandez in an insightful comment below, this would not, however, be an exceedingly good idea. Each instance of Pickup would hold its own texture instance, despite the textures being the same, wasting memory. Furthermore, Pickup could no longer use the default copy operations, as a copied Pickup's Sprite instance would subsequently refer to the texture instance in the original object.

A better approach would be to move the handling of this issue, i.e. management of texture instances and their lifetime, outside the Pickup class itself. 
There is a multitude of possible solutions ranging from simple functions doing internal caching to more complicated resource manager classes.

The former could be as simple as the following snippet:

```
const Texture& load(const std::string &filename)
{
    static std::map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<Texture>> textures;
    auto &tex_ptr=textures[filename];
    if(!tex_ptr)
        tex_ptr=std::make_unique<Texture>(filename);
    return *tex_ptr;
}
```

This simplistic version does, of course, have a minor "leak" as unused textures will never be freed during the programs execution.

Googling "texture manager sfml" will yield many examples and tutorials regarding the latter, for instance [this rather old unofficial one](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/wiki/Tutorial:-Image-Manager) in SFML's github. It manages sf::Image, not sf::Texture, but the same general ideas apply.

Comment: But what if I have multiple textures?

Comment: In that case you would have to keep multiple variables(or a vector/array/something else) somewhere. Each Texture instance must somehow outlive its usage by any Sprite instance.

Comment: its not good to use vector for storing textures because when its resized the vector will need to create a new bigger array and copy those textures to that and copying texture is a slow operation. unless you use vector::reserve() if you can foresee the size

Comment: @Peter you should write class that manages your textures (ie resource manager), in that class you can hide a bunch of different texture that can be use to every objects, its also bad to put texture as data member for your pickup,  assuming there will be more than one instances of pickup ( so thats means more than 1 instances of sf::Texture with same textures ), you can also hide static texture in your class if all pickup objects will just use one texture theres more efficient way to do that, but beware of good and bad design of your class

Comment: You are correct, what i suggested as a possible solution was merely the first and simplest that came to mind to fix the problem in the specific case presented, not a good one as such. I will amend my answer with the suggestions in your comment. Thank you ;-)